# How to prevent hacker from downloading SQLite file from the server?

Tags: sqlite

As you know when if a stranger know the path of your SQLite database file he can easy download it. my question is how to avoid that?

Comment: This would be better on [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "As you know when if a stranger know the path of your SQLite database file he can easy download it. " - that's not really true. Just because the file is accessible by the server itself (i.e. the processes running on it) does not mean it has to be exposed via any means to the network. The actual answer would require a lot of information about the environment and the actual problem, so I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're accessing the SQLite database server-side. You could configure whatever host you're using (apache, nginx, etc...) to not allow access to the file or you could change the permissions to the file to only allow you to view it (using `chmod`).